# Does this look right for SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Prompt:
The library provides books to borrowers. Each book is described by title, edition, and year of publication, and is uniquely identified using the ISBN. Each borrower is described by his or her name and address and is uniquely identified using a borrower number. The library provides one or more copies of each book and each copy is uniquely identified using a copy number, status indicating if the book is available for loan, and the allowable loan period for a given copy. A borrower may loan one or many books, and the date each book is loaned out and is returned is recorded. Loan number uniquely identifies each book loan.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS library;
CREATE DATABASE library;`

USE library;


`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE book (
    title   varchar(30) not null,
    edition varchar(10),
    year    char(4),
    ISBN    char(13),
    primary key (ISBN),
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS loan CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE loan (
    return date varchar(10) not null,
    leave date varchar(10),
    primary key (copy_num),
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS borrower CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE borrower (
    Name_first  varchar(25) not null,
    Name_last   varchar(25) not null,
    Address varchar(20),
    borrow_num  char(14),
    primary key (borrow_num),
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS copy CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE copy (
    status  varchar(25) not null,
    loan period varchar(2),
    copy_num    char(13),
    primary key (copy_num),
);
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is valid SQL but you don't need to DROP those tables separately as you are deleting a whole database so the tables in it will also get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

While not necessarily how I'd do it, the requirement is, nevertheless, very clear:

```
ISBN_detail(ISBN*,title, edition,year)
```

(We don't really need to store this, if we have access to an externally maintained catalogue)

```
borrower (borrower_number*,name,address)
```

(I would use a surrogate id here, in case we ever decide to change the borrower numbering system. I would also want to record more information about the status of the borrower, e.g. date joined)

```
book (copy_number*, isbn*, status, loan_period)
```

(Again, I would have surrogate id - I think copy number is a weak concept. Loan_period is the duration (in days) that a book can be borrowed, and note that in real life, some borrowers are sometimes allowed to borrow books longer than others, but that's for another day)

```
loans(loan_number*,borrower_number,copy_number,ISBN,loaned_date [not null],returned_date [null])
```

THIS IS WHY I WOULD HAVE A book_id!!!

This table could have been...

```
loans(borrower_id*,book_id*,loan_date*,returned_date)
```

... but the specification doesn't allow for this.

Note that borrowers can normally borrow only a finite amount of books at any one time, but again, that's not part of this assignment .

```
* = (component of) PRIMARY KEY
```